# Amount of EM radiation (and particles) Earth "receives" from other planets in our solar system?

Tags: the-sun, planet, radiation

Can it be (or has it been already?) measured how much and what kind of EM radiation (apart from visible light)/particles Earth "receives" from a specific planet in our solar system?

Can other planets (giants like Jupiter/Saturn) also emit neutrinos or some other high energetic particles (like Sun)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course all the planets have been observed by many telescopes at different wavelengths. Yes, they do emit energy at wavelengths other than in the visible part of the spectrum.

Broadly speaking, the peak of their output depends on their temperatures. Most of the light from the outer giant planets emerges in the infrared for example.

However, some planets also are strong radio emitters. For example Jupiter has a strong magnetic field that accelerates charged particles which then emit radio waves.

Neutrinos are hard to pinpoint - telescopes currently struggle to say exactly where they come from in the sky. The planets are not expected to be strong neutrino emitters.